# Domain of a two variables function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to draw the domain of a two variables function. I did it, but not sure my answer is correct. I can't load images due to being new here, so I will describe what I got, and hopefully you can verify. The function is:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{9-x^{2}-y^{2}}}{\ln(\frac{x^{2}}{4}+\frac{y^{2}}{16}-1)}$$
My domain contains 2 ellipses, one circle, for positive values of x or zero only. Am I correct ? My main question is, are there 2 ellipses in this domain or only 1 ? I think 2, because you have the inside of the ln which needs to be > 0 and you have the ln itself that should not be 0, meaning the inside is not 1

Answer (score 0):

I've chalked up your description (in Paint, no less) below.

I agree that you have to stay either on or inside the brown circle. Also, you need to stay on the half-plane corresponding to the non-negative part of the $x$-axis.

Regarding the inner ellipse, you have to stay strictly *outside* this ellipse in order for $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{16}>1$ to be true, and as you yourself point out, you should also avoid landing on the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{16}=2$.

[image: domain]

Comment: Thank you very much, your Paint figure is very helpful.